Independence of Random Variables with Uniform Distribution (Counter Example?)
Suppose a finite set $M$ and two random variables $X$ and $Y$ (that are not almost surely equal!) both uniformly distributed on $M$, i.e.
$$
\mathbb P(X=m) = \mathbb P(Y=m) = \frac{1}{\lvert M\rvert}
$$
for all $m\in M$.
Question: Is it possible to prove independence of $X$ and $Y$ from this assumption alone, i.e.
$$
\mathbb P(X=m, Y=m') = \frac{1}{\lvert M\rvert^2} = \mathbb P(X=m)\cdot \mathbb P(Y=m')
$$
for all $m,m'\in M$?
My gut immediately tells me No, since for arbitrary distributions this is certainly not true. However, maybe the uniform distribution plays a special role here. So far I did not manage to find a counter example.
Any help is appreciated!

@Surb thats what i excluded it in the first sentence

Indeed, sorry, I thought it was. You can't say anything about the joint distribution if its not given.

Take $M={1,2,...,n}$ and $Y=n-X+1$. Then $X\sim Y\sim U(M)$ but they are dependent.
